# dockerfile simplest automation

Tags: linux, docker

I'm learning docker and create a Dockerfile to fill container with apps. Step1 is Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:alpine as builder

ADD /src/common $GOPATH/src/common
ADD /src/ins_signal_node $GOPATH/src/ins_signal_node
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/ins_signal_node
RUN go build -o /go/bin/signal_server .

ADD /src/ins_full_node $GOPATH/src/ins_full_node
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/ins_full_node
RUN go build -o /go/bin/full_node .

FROM alpine
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/signal_server     /go/bin/signal_server
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/full_node /go/bin/full_node
COPY run_test.sh /go/bin
```

No questions here - it's ok. After this I run my script to rebuild and run this Container and enter it's bash - Step2:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker container rm -f full
docker image rm -f ss

docker build -t ss .
winpty docker run -it --name full ss
```

So at this moment I'm in containers console. And as it scripted I ran 2 commands - Step3

```
cd go/bin/
./run_test.sh
```

It works!
But. After Step2 - when I'm in console - I want Step 3 - run the starter script to be automated. So at the end of my Dockerfile from Step1 I add line

```
CMD ["cd go/bin/ && ./run_test.sh"]
```

And after I ran Step2 - with full start now - I've got the error message:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"cd go/bin/ && ./run_test.sh\": stat cd go/bin/ && ./run_test
>   .sh: no such file or directory": unknown.

And if I ran this CMD - cd go/bin/ && ./run_test.sh - manualy when I'm in container's console - it works!
So my question - what's bad with my

```
CMD ["cd go/bin/ && ./run_test.sh"]
```

**UPDATE**

Ok. I try now with ["/go/bin/run_test.sh"] and ["./go/bin/run_test.sh"] and got

```
initializing…
/go/bin/run_test.sh: line 2: ./signal_server: not found
starting…
/go/bin/run_test.sh: line 10: ./full_node: not found
/go/bin/run_test.sh: line 9: ./full_node: not found
/go/bin/run_test.sh: line 8: ./full_node: not found
/go/bin/run_test.sh: line 7: ./full_node: not found
```

**UPDATE 2**
So in my Dockerfile I create

```
FROM alpine
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/signal_server /go/bin/signal_server
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/full_node /go/bin/full_node
COPY run_test.sh /go/bin
COPY entry_point.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["./entry_point.sh"]
```

entry_point.sh - and has entry_point.sh in the root. If I use ENTRYPOINT - it says

> standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), CMD syntax is

```
CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] (exec form, this is the preferred form)
CMD ["param1","param2"] (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
CMD command param1 param2 (shell form)
```

Docker treats your composite command as the name of the executable because you are using double quotes around it. You can easily solve this for example by putting all commands in a script such as `/bin/myscript.sh`, then you just need `CMD /bin/myscript.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Use docker entrypoint in your Dockerfile:

Create a entrypoint.sh with:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cd go/bin/
./run_test.sh
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile on last line:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the run command to your entrypoint script:

```
cd /go/bin \
&& ./run_test.sh
```

Comment: Ok. This is my only line after shebang. And I get standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"